# Is it a crime to attend the Olympic games after a diplomatic boycott as a civilian if you're a diplomat?

Tags: united-states

https://finance.yahoo.com/news/africa-decision-not-boycott-beijing-093000132.html

> African countries have ignored Washington's call for a diplomatic
> boycott of the Beijing Winter Olympics, instead expressing support for
> China's hosting of the Games and warning that the event should not be
> a platform for politics.

Is it a crime to attend the Olympic games after a diplomatic boycott as a civilian if you're a diplomat? I am wondering if there are legal ramifications to a diplomatic boycott of the Olympic games in the United States, or if the diplomatic ban simply mean that the U.S. won't pay the diplomats to attend the Olympic games as diplomats.

Comment: A US diplomat who attended in their own personal capacity would just be a spectator, and [international spectators aren't allowed at the Beijing games](https://www.travelandleisure.com/travel-news/beijing-olympics-wont-allow-international-spectators).  So the question is probably moot.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Well, either that or a blatant violation of the Logan Act. But the Logan Act is basically a joke anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a crime in the US. It may be a firing offense depending on the nature of the appointment (that is, what exactly do you mean by "diplomat"?) or at least cause for demotion / reassignment. A diplomat from another country could be declared *persona non grata*, but again it is not a crime to act contrary to a governmental boycott call, in the US. This follows from the First Amendment.

Comment: How would the First Amendment allow people to violate boycotts?  Is it because of the freedom to gather peaceably, and is it because First Amendment rights still apply against the US government trying to restrict its citizens outside of its own territory?